# Как добавить тег через JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно написать скрипт, который заменит этот текст на тег , а в качестве содержимого тега  укажет изначальный текст.
Должно получиться:
`<p class="links"><a>google.com</a></p>`
Я пробывал так:

```
let result = document.querySelector('.links');
result.innerHTML = "<a>google.com</a>;"
```

Но это не работает. Сам HTML ниже:

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="links">google.com</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document ------ эта и следующяя главы - твои)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оно вполне всё работает. И это можно спокойно увидеть в инструментах разработчика. Просто, чтобы ссылка стала ссылкой, надо добавить атрибут `href` (читаем доки: http://htmlbook.ru/html/a), который будет указывать на страницу, куда надо перенаправлять.

Т.е.

```
'<a href="https://www.google.com/">google.com</a>;'
```

Comment: Да, я вспомнил сейчас, когда зашел в консоль и посмотрел. Просто забыл Href с ссылкой добавить.
let result = document.querySelector('.links');
let text = result.textContent;
result.innerHTML = `<a href = https://www.google.com/>${text}</a>`
Так все заработало. Спасибо!